# Entity Framework Core query only work with .ToList()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm using *.NET Core 7* and *Entity Framework Core 7.0.13* and I have the following query:

```
var test = _context.Set<T>
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(m => m.MachineOperations!
        .Where(m =>
            m.InsertedAt.Date <= endDate.Date &&
            m.EndTime <= endDate.TimeOfDay &&
            m.InsertedAt.Date >= startDate.Date &&
            m.StartTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay))
    .ThenInclude(m => m.EggQuantities)
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay);

var test2 = _mapper.ProjectTo<MachineScheduleDataDto>(test);
```

My problem is that the `.Where` clause is not being applied. After some tries, I realized that if I add a `.ToList()` at the end of the query and after I convert it using `.AsQueryable()` to pass as an argument to the mapper, the `.Where` clause works fine. Why does it happen? I can't use `.ToList()` because it selects all the properties of the classes that I am querying.

After many tries, I realized that my query was ok, my problem is inside of the .ProjectTo().
For example, if I pass some argumentes that shouldn't return any *MachineOperation*, the query doesn't actually return anything, which is ok, but when the result of the query pass through the `.ProjectTo`, it magically finds some records and brings it to me. It really doesn't make any sense to me.

Result of the query:
[image]

Result of the .ProjectTo():
[image]

MachineScheduleDataDto class:

```
public record MachineScheduleDataDto
{
    public required ICollection<MachineOperationDto> MachineOperationsDto { get; set; }
}

public record MachineOperationDto
{
    public int MachineOperationId { get; set; }
    public EMachineStatus MachineStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual required MachineScheduleDataDto MachineScheduleDto { get; set; }
}
```

My Mappers:

```
CreateMap<MachineSchedule, MachineScheduleDataDto>()
    .ForMember(p => p.MachineOperationsDto, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.MachineOperations));

CreateMap<MachineOperation, MachineOperationDto>()
   .ForMember(p => p.MachineScheduleDto, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.MachineSchedule));
```

Comment: You have a method and variable test is being returned from the method.  What is the return type of the method?

Comment: It is a IQueryable<MachineScheduleDataDto>

Comment: The method AsQueryable requires an IEnumerable input.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.asqueryable?view=net-7.0

Comment: I'm sorry, I read the article and i usderstood the problem, but how can I apply this to solve my problem?

Comment: The ToList() creates a IEnumerable interface.  If you need a custom IEnumerable interface than use following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-7.0

Comment: What library are you getting that `ProjectTo` from? That doesn't look like Automapper.  Also what is _typedContext? This isn't a DbContext as there is no entity dbset being referenced. This doesn't look like a complete example. It would appear that whatever this `ProjectTo` method is, it doesn't work with IQueryable and it is relying on mapping across an Enumerable rather than projecting into the EF IQueryable. (Which would involve a `ToList` at the end of the `ProjectTo` call. )

Comment: 1. The _typedContext is:  `_typedContext = context.Set<T>();` 

2. The .ProjectTo is from the library AutoMapper version 12.0.1 and it only accept an IQueryable as a source parameter.

Comment: Just a question. Your `Where` condition inside the first `Include` doesn't perform a filter on the returned outer set, only perform a filter on the items loaded from database into `MachineOperations` property.  Is this the intended behaviour? If it is not and you would like to return only items that have `MachineOperations` with the required condition, you must specifiy this condition in the `.Any(mo => .. insert condition here ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is Automapper, though I am not familiar with that flavour of `ProjectTo`, the issue is that you are mixing eager loading /w filtering with `IQueryable` projection. Projection /w `ProjectTo` does not require, and likely ignores eager loading including filtering. If you want to filter the projections, do it via the mapping configuration. So if you have a MachineScheduleDataDto which contains MachineOperationDtos, your mapping for building a MachineScheduleDataDto should include the rules about what MachineOperations to include. I.e:

```
var configuration = new AutomapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MachineScheduleData, MachineScheduleDataDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.MachineOperationsDtos, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MachineOperations
               .Where(m =>
                  m.InsertedAt.Date <= endDate.Date &&
                  m.EndTime <= endDate.TimeOfDay &&
                  m.InsertedAt.Date >= startDate.Date &&
                  m.StartTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay)));
});
```

The configuration will obviously have the mappings for the MachineOperation -> MachineOperationDto etc. as well and will use those mappings to map the resulting filtered machine operations into their DTOs. Then your resulting query would look like:

```
var query= _context.Set<MachineScheduleDatas>
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay);

var dtos = await_mapper.ProjectTo<MachineScheduleDataDto>(query)
    .ToListAsync();
```

or what I'm more familiar with the `ProjectTo` extension method:

```
var dtops = await _context.Set<MachineScheduleDatas>
    .Where(m =>
        diffDays.Contains(m.WeekDay) &&
        m.MachineOperations!.Any() &&
        m.InitialProductionTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay &&
        m.FinalProductionTime >= startDate.TimeOfDay)
    .ProjectTo<MachineScheduleDataDto>(configuration)
    .ToListAsync();
```